# Leetcode Missing Number Exercise Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have begun to use LeetCode, and I don't understand why my code doesn't pass the test case where the input is [0] (the expected output should be 1).

Brief: Given an array containing n distinct numbers taken from 0, 1, 2, ..., n, find the one that is missing from the array.

Example 1:

Input: [3,0,1]
Output: 2

Code:

```
class Solution:
  def missingNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
      largest = max(nums)
      wholeList = list(range(0, largest+1))

      for i in wholeList:
          if wholeList[i] not in nums:
              return wholeList[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your brief it doest make sense return 1 because the your fisrt item in array is zero and the last item is zero, between 0. and 0, no one is missing.

but you can try something like this

```py
class Solution:
  def missingNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
      largest = max(nums)
      wholeList = list(range(0, largest+2))

      for i in wholeList:
          if wholeList[i] not in nums:
              return wholeList[i]
```

or

```py
class Solution:
  def missingNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
      if len(nums) == 1: return nums[0] + 1
      largest = max(nums)
      wholeList = list(range(0, largest+1))

      for i in wholeList:
          if wholeList[i] not in nums:
              return wholeList[i]
```